# Speed not updating when using GeoCoordinateWatcher

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation

When using the `GeoCoordinateWatcher` class to get updated GPS position and speed inside my  Windows Phone application, the latitude and longitude updates, but the speed remains at a constant value: `5.95` (as well as the course).

I initialize the Geo Watcher with the following code:

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher GeoWatcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
```

And start the listening process using the snipped:

```
GeoWatcher.StatusChanged += GeoWatcherStatusChanged;
GeoWatcher.PositionChanged += OnGeoWatcherPositionChanged;
GeoWatcher.MovementThreshold = 0.5;
GeoWatcher.Start();
```

And finally, the method `OnGeoWatcherPositionChanged` contains the following code:

```
textSpeed.Text = args.Position.Location.Speed.ToString();
```

Where `textSpeed` is a simple `TextBox`.

Does anyone know why Speed remains at a constant value? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm running into the same issue..